# Script for clean up some GID in Google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

i have a simply code to clean up a first sheet

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var first = ss.getSheetByName("sheet1");
  first.clear();
}
```

But i would like to not the first but all another sheet in the same file ( gid ).

i can't find a solution.

can you help me.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

#### Pattern 1:

If you want to use `clear()` for the specific sheets by the sheet IDs (GID) in the active Spreadsheet, you can use the following script.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var sheetIds = ["###sheetId1###", "###sheetId2###",,,]; // Please set the sheet IDs (GID) here.

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  sheets.forEach(sheet => {
    if (sheetIds.includes(sheet.getSheetId())) {
      sheet.clear();
    }
  });
}
```

- When you want to check the sheet name instead of sheet ID, you can also use the following script.

  ```
    function myFunction() {
      var sheetIds = ["###sheetName1###", "###sheetName2###",,,]; // Please set the sheet name here.

      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      var sheets = ss.getSheets();
      sheets.forEach(sheet => {
        if (sheetIds.includes(sheet.getSheetName())) {
          sheet.clear();
        }
      });
    }
  ```

#### Pattern 2:

If you want to use `clear()` for all sheets in the active Spreadsheet, you can use the following script.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  sheets.forEach(sheet => sheet.clear());
}
```

#### Reference:

- [getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets)

Comment: hi, thanks of you answer i have used the " pattern2 " for my script because the " Pattern 1" not work with gid.

Comment: @Mickael Lesouef Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `the " Pattern 1" not work with gid.`, unfortunately, the pattern 1 can be used with the sheet ID (gid). So, can you provide your current script for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.